# Angularjs uigrid - confirm dialog box

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How can I implement a 'confirm delete' dialog box from a cell link on each row of the ui-grid?

Comment: add some code, and some more context

Comment: With this cell template in my column definition of uigrid, I want to display a 'confirm delete' dialog box before executing the deleteRow function.

cellTemplate:
'<div title="Delete" style="float: left;" ng-click="grid.appScope.deleteRow(row.entity)"></div>'